# How can we split the word into characters in android/java..?? and assign particular id to each character

Tags: java, android

I want to separate the word into characters like "ABCD" into A.B.C.D. and after that
If we assume A=1 , B=2 ,...... and Z= 26, then i want to assign this sequence to each character and make a sum of that to achieved the output.
How this can be done..??

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you want to split and join them on `.`, if your ultimate goal is to assign `numbers` to each characters and find the sum?

Comment: i suppose this question pertains to string manipulation and not java/android specific.

Comment: yes this is what exactly i want..assign numbers to each character and find the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have maintained a `map` for mapping your `characters` with some `numbers`. Then you can simply split your string on `empty string` to get individual characters. And then iterate over your array to get the sum.

Note, that, splitting on `empty string` will get you an empty string as first element in array. Because, a string in Java contains an `empty` string at the start of string.

So, you can try out this code: -

```
    String str = "ABCDEF";
    String[] arr = str.split("");
    int sum = 0;

    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
        {
            put("A", 1); put("B", 2); put("C", 3);
            put("D", 4); put("E", 5); put("F", 6);
        }
    };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    // Iteration starts from index 1, as 1st element is an empty string
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        sum += map.get(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
```

**OUTPUT: -**: -

```
[, A, B, C, D, E, F]
Sum = 21
```

---

Or, you can also use [`String#toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method, to directly convert your string into `character array` with individual characters. In that case, your map declaration should be like: - `Map<Character, Integer>`

```
String str = "ABCDEF";
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>() {
        {
            put('A', 1); put('B', 2); put('C', 3);
            put('D', 4); put('E', 5); put('F', 6);
        }
};
for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {
    sum += map.get(ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 0;
for (char ch: theWordToCount.toCharArray()) {
     sum += ((int)ch) - 64;
}
```

Since the ASCII code for 'A' is 65, this will add +1 for A, +2 for B and so on.

You will have to deal with upper and lower case, e.g. for lower case subtract 96.

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
String data = "ABCD";

        int sum=0;
        String dataToProcess = data.toLowerCase();
        for(int i=0;i<dataToProcess.length();i++){
            char c = dataToProcess.charAt(i);

            sum += c - 96;
        }

        System.out.println("sum is "+sum);
```